# Uninstalling Qt Creator 2 from Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, uninstallation

I am new to Mac and recently installed Qt Creator 2. I am not sure where I installed this piece of software. How do I uninstall it cleanly...Is there any uninstalling app that does this cleanly???

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Howto_do_a_clean_uninstall_and_reinstall_of_qt_sdk):

1) sudo QtSDK/SDKMaintenanceTool.app/Contents/MacOS/SDKMaintenanceTool

a) In newer versions replace both instances of SDKMaintenanceTool with MaintenanceTool.

b) If not QtSDK, check for /Users/YourUserName/QtX.Y.Z where X.Y.Z is a Qt version.

2) The tool’s dialog window will show up. In the dialog window select “Remove all components”.

3) Click the Continue button, the the Uninstall button to confirm. Qt SDK will be uninstalled and QtSDK directory will be removed.

4) Run the QtSDK installer if reinstallation is needed.

5) In the installation dialog window, make sure to check the box “Remove the old Qt Creator’s setting”.

6) Continue to finish the installation.

Alternatively, you could try running the following command, but I have never tried it myself:

```
sudo python /Developer/Tools/uninstall-qt.py
```

Comment: I am not able to find QtSDK directory. Neither there is any directory with the name QtX.Y.Z in the directory structure specified.

Comment: @Wizard: how did you install it?

Comment: I downloaded and installed Qt from http://qt-project.org/downloads. I downloaded the qt creator and Qt 4.8 manually. I am not sure where I installed it now.

Comment: you mean, you installed them separately and not as a whole SDK?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to install a old version, so had to download it that way.

Comment: @Wizard: ok, you have not mentioned that in the question. Did you get it solved?

Comment: I want to uninstall too and doing these steps but it ask me for a password. I don't use any password to login my mac. I doesn't accept any password I try..how do I come around that? thanks